# Why do floats whose width is percentage behave differently inside a container with a sibling vs if their width is in pixels?

Tags: html, css

```css
.container {
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px 2px yellow;
}

img {
    vertical-align: bottom;  
}


.overlay {
    background-color: skyblue;
    width:;
    float:left;
}
```

```html
<div class="container"> 

<img src="https://athome.reachtheworld.org/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/NYC.jpg">

<div class="overlay">
  Text
</div>

</div>
```

In this example, the width of the float is the size of its content, the text, and the container has expanded just enough to contain both siblings.

Now, if i increase the width of the float in pixels, the float will start pushing the sibling, which will expand the container.

```css
.container {
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px 2px yellow;
}

img {
    vertical-align: bottom;  
}


.overlay {
    background-color: skyblue;
    width:100px;
    float:left;
}
```

```html
<div class="container"> 

<img src="https://athome.reachtheworld.org/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/NYC.jpg">

<div class="overlay">
  Text
</div>

</div>
```

You might have to use the full screen on the snippet to see it.

Now, if i use percentage instead of pixels on the width of the float, the container only expands as much as to contain the text of the float, while the extra width does not push the sibling. Instead the float is pushed down on a new line, and the extra width on the container remains to be seen on the right side. Why is this happening?

Or to be more specific, the width of the float does push the sibling but only until there's no more space, then the float is pushed down, and it keeps expanding on a new line, while the container maintains the width space of the original float size.

```css
.container {
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px 2px yellow;
}

img {
    vertical-align: bottom;  
}


.overlay {
    background-color: skyblue;
    width:10%;
    float:left;
}
```

```html
<div class="container"> 

<img src="https://athome.reachtheworld.org/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/NYC.jpg">

<div class="overlay">
  Text
</div>

</div>
```

Here's a screenshot to illustrate my question.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qVPEU.jpg)

I sort of understand that the float is based on percentage, so the container has to maintain that ratio, but even if both siblings are based on percentage, and then you increase the percentage of one of them, the container still maintains the width of when both siblings had perfect 100% width.

Here's what i mean:

```css
.container {
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px 2px yellow;
}

img {
    vertical-align: bottom;  
    width:90%;

}


.overlay {
    background-color: skyblue;
    width:10%;
    float:left;
}
```

```html
<div class="container"> 

<img src="https://athome.reachtheworld.org/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/NYC.jpg">

<div class="overlay">
  Text
</div>

</div>
```

Now, you see how both sibling take exactly 100%, but now if you make the width of the float 20%, it will be pushed down, as there is no more space, but the container will remain the same width as it was before based on the float being 10% only. This is what i mean. Why does it maintain that width?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Percentage need a reference so in order to find the percentage width of the childs we first need to know the one of the parent element which is also based on its content. We have a loop.

In such case, we first consider the width of the childs to be auto in order to identify the width of the parent then we use that width to calculate the one of the child elements and the size of the parent element will **no more change** (otherwise we will have an infinite loop).

Here is an illustration to better understand

```css
.container {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  border: 10px solid yellow;
  margin:5px;
}

img {
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

.overlay {
  background-color: skyblue;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<p>Initial state</p>
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/17/200/200">

  <div class="overlay">
    Text
  </div>
</div>
<p>let use some percentage</p>
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/17/200/200" style="width:20%">

  <div class="overlay" style="width:80%">
    Text
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/17/200/200" style="width:80%">

  <div class="overlay" style="width:80%">
    Text
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/17/200/200" style="width:40%">

  <div class="overlay">
    Text
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/17/200/200" style="width:100%">

  <div class="overlay" style="width:100%">
    Text
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/17/200/200" style="width:200%">

  <div class="overlay" style="width:150%">
    Text
  </div>
</div>
```

You can clearly notice that in all the cases, the width of the parent remain unchanged and the child will use that width as a reference for their calculation. That width was initially calculated based on the default width of the text and the image.

Using pixel value is a different story as we don't have any complex calcuation and the parent will adjust its width based on the childs:

```css
.container {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  border: 10px solid yellow;
  margin:5px;
}

img {
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

.overlay {
  background-color: skyblue;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<p>Initial state</p>
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/17/200/200">

  <div class="overlay">
    Text
  </div>
</div>
<p>let use some percentage</p>
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/17/200/200" style="width:20px">

  <div class="overlay" style="width:80px">
    Text
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/17/200/200" style="width:80px">

  <div class="overlay" style="width:80px">
    Text
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/17/200/200" style="width:40px">

  <div class="overlay">
    Text
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/17/200/200" style="width:100px">

  <div class="overlay" style="width:100px">
    Text
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/17/200/200" style="width:200px">

  <div class="overlay" style="width:150px">
    Text
  </div>
</div>
```

For more accurate details you can refer to the specification: https://www.w3.org/TR/css-sizing-3/#intrinsic-contribution

Comment: Hi. Why when i have a float and an img sibling like my example above, and then i use height 100% to the float, it doesn't fill the 100% of the container despite the container being enlarged by the image?

Comment: the height of the container should be as big as the img, so why isn't the float filling it?

Comment: @ILoveCoffee height or width?

Comment: height. Please look at the jsfiddle.

Comment: the float element has a height of 100%, yet it doesn't fill the container. Why?

Comment: @ILoveCoffee like width, height with a percentage need a reference and in this case the behavior is undefined, unlike with width so percentage value won't work

Comment: But why is the height of the container undefined? Isn't the height of the image defining the height of the container?

Comment: @ILoveCoffee it's the height of the content (text + image). it's a bit tricky but height doesn't behave the same as width and percentage in such case is an undefined behavior and it will resolve to auto. Follow the link I shared and scroll to Example 6 to understand. I will try to bring another related question